# Compass watch and .sass-cache

Tags: ruby, windows, sass, compass-sass, easyphp

*(I added the line wp-content/themes/klasik-child/mysass/.sass-cache in the file .gitignore from)* when I execute "Compass watch" I have this error:

```
Errno::ENOENT on line ["247"] of C: No such file or directory'
 -C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\github2015\myproject\wp-content\themes\klasik-child\mysass\.sass-cache\75fcaf1b4852ceb732871195e41567cc2a7d8997
C%058C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\github2015
run with --trace to see the full backtrace
```

Yet 75fcaf1b4852ceb732871195e41567cc2a7d8997 and github2015 folder exists.

I reset my .gitingnore file and I tried to delete the folder ".sass-cache"
but I still have the same problem.

I tried adding `sass_options = {:cache_location => "path\to\tmp\sass-cache"}` in config.rb but it gives errors `"mkdir" invalid argument - path`

thank !

++ Other info :

1- Command is run here : C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\github2015\myproject\wp-content\themes\klasik-child\mysass
from windows command

2- directory structure

```
mysass
|---css
     |----principal.css
|---images
|---sass
     |----partials
           |-----_accueil.scss
     |----pricipal.scss
config.rb
```

3- **config.rb**

```
require 'compass/import-once/activate'

http_path = "/"
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "javascripts"
# sass_options = {:cache_location => "path\to\tmp\sass-cache"}
relative_assets = true
line_comments = false
```

Comment: I don't understand how you're getting this error, you added "wp-content/themes/klasik-child/mysass/.sass-cache" to what?  Your .gitignore has nothing to do with anything.

Comment: no, I was wrong, I added this line wp-content/themes/klasik-child/mysass/.sass-cache. I added to the file .gitignore. I use GitHub.

Comment: GitHub has nothing to do with Sass or Compass, and by extension, .gitignore has nothing to do with Sass or Compass.

Comment: ok, so I can't execute "Compass watch", forget .gitignore

Comment: You haven't provided anything here that would help anyone reproduce this error.  There's no config.rb, there's no information about the directory structure or the location where you are running the command.

Comment: ok ! Thank you, I completed my question.

Comment: It seems that the problem exists only with PARTIALS. When I change the file pricipal.scss no compilation problem. But when I change a file _accueil.scss of type I errors 'No such file or directory ...sass-cache/..'

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution here: [Compass/SASS - not all files are compiled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23680422/compass-sass-not-all-files-are-compiled)

Indeed, 
The problem exists only if I change _accueil.scss (PARTIALS).
When I change pricipal.scss no compilation problem.
When I change _accueil.scss of type I errors 'No such file or directory ...sass-cache/..' –

If I comment the first line of config.rb `# require 'compass/import-once/activate'` it is no more problem of compilation : all my stylesheets they are compiled normally.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue it turns out my **.sass-cache** path was too long, and the file was silently failing and not being outputted to that directory. It never mentioned anywhere that my path was too long, I was trying a suggestion found here:

https://github.com/Compass/compass/issues/1791

To fix it,
Add this line to to your **config.rb**

```
cache_path = 'C:\temp\sass'
```